# How to get a segment URL cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Hi I got trouble in retrieve URL segment CAkephp3 in view. I want to get the ID from current URL.

Lets say my URL is http://localhost/admin/financial_agreements/edit/50
and I want redirect to http://localhost/admin/financial_agreements/do_print/50
simply :

```
var urlPrint = "<?=$this->Url->build(['controller' => 'financial_agreements', 'action' => 'do_print', 'I NEED ID FROM CURRENT'], true)?>";
```

I try debug

```
<?=debug($this->Url->build()); die();?>
```

But its produce : admin/financial_agreements/edit/50

whats called in 50 ? I need that 50 inside my "url->build" urlPrint

sorry for bad english.

Anyhelp will appreciate.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Request object to get request data (including url parameters) within views.

Try this in your view:

`$this->request->getParam('pass')  //CakePHP 3.4+`

`$this->request->params['pass']  // CakePHP 3.3`

That will return an array of all non-named parameters that were passed after the action's name in the URL. Example: `/mycontroller/myaction/param1/param2`. So in this example, `$this->request->getParam('pass')` will produce an array like: `[0 => 'param1', 1 => 'param2']`.

Bonus answer: you can also 'name' parameters in the URL, like: `/mycontroller/myaction/some_name:some_value`. To retrieve this kind of named parameters, you would do the same trick but using: `$this->request->getParam('named')` (Use the argument 'named' instead of 'pass').

More info:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#passed-arguments

Comment: Note that named parameters are deprecated as of Cake 3. You can instead use more standard URL query strings like `?some_name=some_value`, and access them with `$this->request->getQuery('some_name')`. This is discussed on the same links @YOMorales provided.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I forgot about the deprecation. I still do like named params. :P

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your edit function follows standard practices, you'll have something like this:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $financialAgreement = $this->FinancialAgreements->get($id);
    ...
    $this->set(compact('financialAgreement'));
}
```

Then in `edit.ctp`, you can get the id of the current record very simply as `$financialAgreement->id`, so your URL will be generated with

```
$this->Url->build(['controller' => 'financial_agreements', 'action' => 'do_print', $financialAgreement->id], true)
```